# Procedure for login authentication test case in phpunit laravel

Tags: phpunit, laravel-5.1

What is the procedure for login authentication phpunit test cases in laravel 5 ?

```
$credentials=[
  'email'=>'admin@admin.com',
  'password'=>'admin'
];
$response=$this->call('POST','login',$credentials);
$this->assertTrue($response->isOk());
```

Answer (score 0):

This one will only check if the user is existed and able to login, however I don't see why we need this test:

```
$this->assertTrue(Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password]));
```

Probably the following test is better for a unit test case. Here you want to check if the redirection of your route is working correctly if the login fail/success. I'd write it your code as:

```
$credentials=[
   'email'=>'admin@admin.com',
   'password'=>'admin'
];
$this->call('POST','login',$credentials);
$this->assertResponseOk();
//or $this->assertRedirectedToRoute('login.fail');
```